# TypeError: Cannot read property 'awaitMessages' of null

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get the bot to output the user input from dm to the console, but it keeps returning this error code. I tried `person.dmChannel.awaitMessages`, but received the same error, and I also tried `person.id.dmChannel.awaitMessages`, but received the same error.

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);
    const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });
    const config = require('./config.json');
    client.on("message", (message) => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        const person = message.author;
        if (message.content === "!match") {
            message.channel.send("<@" + message.author.id + "> please check your Dm")
            person.send("blah blah blah ? ? ")
            person.dmChannel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 300000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then((collected) => {
                    console.log(collected.size)
                    const msg = collected.first()
                    console.log(msg.content)
                })
        }
    })
    client.login(config.token)
```

Comment: Due to your syntax it seems like you are on v13. I just wanted to let you know that the `message` event is deprecated. Use `messageCreate` instead on v13

Answer (score 2):

[`User.dmChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=dmChannel) is not guaranteed to have a value. You should use [`User.createDM`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) instead.

```js
const dm = await person.createDM()
//keep in mind createDM is an async function and needs to be awaited (in async callback)
dm.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 300000, errors: ['time'] })
```